# Plotting images of data from TensorFlow datasets, shows one image only

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I was working on the Fashion MNIST dataset on TensorFlow, I was trying to plot the image of the train_data of having a specific test_label. I ran the following code, it works but it only shows me one image even though there are many such images.

```
for i in range (len(test_data)):
  if test_labels[i]==9:
    plt.imshow(test_data[i])
```

following is the output I am getting:

[image]

Comment: ‘plt.imshow’ will just print one image per cell, so you just see the last image from class 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It overwrites the previous plot each time you iterate over test data.

If you want to get different plots, use something like this:

```
j = 0
n_rows = 2
n_cols = 3
for i in range(len(test_data)):
    if test_labels[i]==9:
        j += 1
        ax = plt.subplot(n_rows,n_cols,j)
        ax.imshow(test_data[i])
    if j >= (n_rows*n_cols):
        break
```

The result:
[image: plotted image]